# uiviewcontroller of smaller size

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, toast, presentviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development and am trying to make a custom toast by using UIViewController of smaller size and presenting it modally. I want that when the view controller is presented, the background screen remains responsive (clickable/scrollable) but at the moment, the background screen becomes unresponsive until the presented view controller is dismissed. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Edit 1:**
This is the function inside NotificationToastViewController which is called to show the toast.

```
class func popup(with presentable: NotificationToastPresentable, onViewDidAppear: (() -> ())? = nil, onDismiss: ((CloseStatus) -> ())? = nil, bool1: Bool = false, bool2: Bool = false) {
    let popupViewController = NotificationToastViewController()
    popupViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    let _ = popupViewController.view
    popupViewController.configureWith(presentable)
    popupViewController.onViewDidAppear = onViewDidAppear
    popupViewController.onDismiss = onDismiss

    if bool1 {
        popupViewController.statusLabelConstraintToBottom?.constant = 12.0
        popupViewController.statusLabelLeadingConstraint?.constant = 10.0
        popupViewController.statusLabelConstraintWithIcon?.isActive = false
    } else {
        popupViewController.statusLabelConstraintToBottom?.isActive = false
        popupViewController.statusLabelLeadingConstraint?.isActive = false
    }

    if bool2 {
        popupViewController.heightConstrainOfCtaButton?.isActive = false
    }
    UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController()?.present(popupViewController, animated: true)
}
```

This is the view hierarchy in the xib:
[image: This is the view hierarchy in the xib:]

Comment: It is easy to add a custom UIView as toast to the view of UIViewController directly rather presenting it in the way modally. Even you can make it as reusable and can add it where ever you want by setting up the frame of the view.

Comment: If you don't like view you can add container views to any viewcontroller. But for the sake of simplicity and reusability adding view is good choice .

Comment: @Sateesh How do you show a custom uiview as toast? I have created an xib for the custom uiview. I feel that the reason for it blocking might be that i am using safeview to add constraints for the custom uiview and that might be the reason it completely blocks the ui since safe view occupies the entire screen?

Comment: @Priyanshu, can you please share the code what you have tried so far, if you don't mind ?

Comment: @Sateesh please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something of this sort:

```
var vc = SecondController()
    self.addChild(vc)
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view!)
    vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vc.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
    vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
    vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    vc.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Where SecondViewController is another ViewController class, which you have to add as a child Controller to your home controller and then set the constraints of the second controller's view. I believe the result of such an implementation is what you are trying to achieve.